# web scraping issue (tried curl, wget, headless chrome, phantomjs but still having trouble...)

Tags: curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to set up a monitor to check a site for my elderly parents to get their covid shot so they don't have to sit at the computer and press refresh every 5 minutes.

All I need to do is get some sort of html from a website (then I can search for keywords, send emails/texts/etc. just fine on my own based on the results).

the website is
https://apps6.health.ny.gov/doh2/applinks/cdmspr/2/counties?OpID=50503446

if I visit in chrome/firefox, I can download it to html just fine
and the result looks like this:
https://i.postimg.cc/KvS6cXR9/screenshot-11.png

however regardless of the method I choose and parameters I enter, all of the CLI attempts have yielded this:
https://i.postimg.cc/bwTcF6Ym/screenshot-11.png
(e.g., from running curl -k "https://apps6.health.ny.gov/doh2/applinks/cdmspr/2/counties?OpID=50503446" -o output.txt)

I've also tried using a more custom curl command from the chrome debugger (i.e., https://i.postimg.cc/kGnWwXT1/screenshot-11.png) but that still yielded the same result (though perhaps I may have run it slightly wrong as the command generated isn't 100% compatible with windows as is...)

any ideas?

I'd prefer not to do this manually or via GUI scripting...

I did try headless chrome (not pupeteer though) via the below

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="C:\Data\a-ad hoc\2021-01-17a\New Folder (2)\testny.pdf" https://apps6.health.ny.gov/doh2/applinks/cdmspr/2/counties?OpID=50503446

and all I got was this
https://i.postimg.cc/nLWGq782/screenshot-11.png

Comment: impressive, they've really made it difficult: each cookie-less request to your url is served an encrypted cookie in a javascript variable named `bobcmn`, they then proceed to decrypt that cookie with javascript and add the result to a 2nd invocation to your url with the decrypted cookie included. also the cookies are 1-time-use, the cookie is protected against replay attacks; a headless browser is definitely the way to go.

Comment: wow I feel better about not figuring this out as I'm not into webdev at all - I just know the basics of how it works... I did try headless chrome (I updated the above with what I attempted) and that didn't work either... it seems when I disable javascript the website still loads sufficiently though suggesting to me a headless browser isn't necessary (that said, I haven't tried that in a browser after I deleted cookies so maybe I would need something headless (or even "headed" if necessary via windows scripting/ahk/ in a vm (my last stupid resort for these tasks...ugh...)

Comment: javascript is required. try opening the page in incognito with javascript disabled, here's the page you'll get: https://i.imgur.com/9PO4240.png

Comment: any idea why headless chrome wouldn't work as I tried it? (I don't particularly want to install puppeteer for this)

Comment: headless chrome should work if you just give it ~5 seconds to load before taking the screenshot.

Comment: I tried it using virtual-time-budget but it still didn't work, i.e., "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" --headless --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf="C:\Data\a-ad hoc\2021-01-17a\New Folder (3)\plats.pdf" https://apps5.health.ny.gov/doh2/applinks/cdmspr/2/counties?OpID=50503461 --virtual-time-budget=10000